# how to get value of li tag which is in ul tag using getElementById

Tags: javascript, html

In this code I am getting in alert 0 insteadof 'abc'

```
<ul>
    <li>First Node</li>
    <li id="repoFolder" value="abc">Lazy Node</li>
</ul>
<button onclick="rootFolder()">Click Me</button>
```

JS:

```
function rootFolder() {
    alert(document.getElementById("repoFolder").value);
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to read attribute value, since [`HTMLLiElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLLIElement) doesn't have `value` property:

```
document.getElementById("repoFolder").getAttribute("value");
```

And since `value` attribute is not defined in the specification for `li` tag, it's better to use data-attribute (with `.getAttribute("data-value")`):

```
<li id="repoFolder" data-value="abc">Lazy Node</li>
```

Then HTML will be valid and IDE's won't complain about unknown attributes.

Check the demo below.

```js
function rootFolder() {
    alert(document.getElementById("repoFolder").getAttribute('data-value'));
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>First Node</li>
    <li id="repoFolder" data-value="abc">Lazy Node</li>
</ul>
<button onclick="rootFolder()">Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using `getAttribute()`:

```js
function rootFolder() {
  alert(document.getElementById("repoFolder").getAttribute('value'));
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>First Node</li>
  <li id="repoFolder" value="abc">Lazy Node</li>
</ul>
<button onclick="rootFolder()">Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You only have to replace the line

   alert(document.getElementById("repoFolder").value);
   with

   alert(document.getElementById("repoFolder").getAttribute('value'));

Answer (score 1):

Add the following line:

```
alert(document.getElementById("repoFolder").getAttribute('value'));
```